# Mouse sensitivity in 14.04 dissapeared

Tags: mouse, settings, 14.04

If I go to "Settings -> Mouse & Touchpad" in Ubuntu 14.04 all the options are gone! How can I bring them back?

[image: Imgur]

Answer (score 9):

Well, it's a bug...you can sign up here for this bug report gain visibility https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/1303086

Meanwhile, you can tweak xset through startup apps to gain mouse speed.

In my case, this works:

> xset m 20/12 0